# Sorting an ArrayList of String arrays using compareTo() method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am new to java.

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList of String arrays using `String.compareTo()`.

I have compiled the code so that the output is:

> Causality,is,a,relationship
>
> It,is,also,called,causation
>
> It,is,about,a,cause,and,its,affect

Now I want to sort that code (lexicographically) so the output is:

> Causality,a,is,relationship
>
> It,also,called,causation,is
>
> It,a,about,affect,and,cause,is,its

However I am generating some crazy output.

My code is below.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have worked on this probably very simple problem for hours and I am ready to destroy my computer. Thanks

```
public class Wk5Q5 {

    void process1 () {

        String s1 = "Causality is a relationship";
        String s2 = "It is also called causation";
        String s3 = "It is about a cause and its affect";


        ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();


        String[] arr1 = s1.split(" ");
        list.add(arr1);
        String[] arr2 = s2.split(" ");
        list.add(arr2);
        String[] arr3 = s3.split(" ");
        list.add(arr3);

        /**
         * previously sorted the arraylist of string arrays so that
         * each word is separated by commas
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).length; j++){
                String t = list.get(i)[j];

                if (j > 0){
                    t = ", " + t;   
                }
                System.out.print(t);
                //System.out.println(list.get(i)[j]);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        /**
         * my attempt at sorting each string in each list 
         */
        for(int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++){
            for(int i = 0; i < list.get(z).length; i++){
                String x = list.get(z)[i];
                for (int j = i+1; j < list.get(z).length; j++){
                    String y = list.get(z)[j];
                    if(y.compareTo(x) < 0) {
                        String temp = list.get(z)[i];
                        x = list.get(z)[j];
                        y = temp;
                    }
                    System.out.print(x);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about `Collections.sort(myList)`?

Comment: @sp00m: this is a typical homework question. I don't think that the OP is allowed to use the standard API. user1622888, if this is indeed homework, you should really explicitly mention it in this (and all future) questions.

Comment: Work on a single sentence first, rather than on a list of sentences. Once you'll get your sort algorithm, it will be easy to apply it on the list.

Comment: Split the code into peaces. Create methods, attributes of the class.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your implementation of the [*selection sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) algorithm is that you do not modify the list being sorted. When you swap `x` and `y`, the elements in the corresponding positions of the list remain in their old places.

If you stop using `x` and `y` and replace their use with `list.get(z)[i]` and `list.get(z)[j]`, your sorting algorithm would produce different results. Better yet, if the homework allows you to use standard library, take a look at a [built-in way of sorting arrays in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Or you could use meaningful variable names (to make the code readable) and reassign them to the list  ;) Or you could write a method that swaps two elements in a list to impress your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Collections.sort` as everyone else is suggesting or do it manually. To do it manually, there are a bunch of different methods. You are going to want to use either a quicksort or a mergesort algorithm. If you don't know what these are, I can explain further; however, if this is HW you will most likely have went over them already

Comment: Alright, seriously? Anyone gonna tell me whats wrong with this, or just downvote it?

Comment: It's been established that he has to use merge sort and that the Collections library is not an option. It's homework.

Comment: @jahroy Where was it established that he had to use a merge sort? I don't see it anywhere. Granted, his code looks like he was trying to do that, but many HW assignments have multiple solutions, I simply provided a different one.